# apt-get error: Unable to find expected entry 'utilities-1.4/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file

Tags: 14.04, apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'utilities-1.4/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do?

Comment: What command is outputting this error?

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: after editing   "sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list " .  i got          deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse

Comment: I'd suggest renaming `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `sourcesbak.list` and then running `sudo apt-get update again`. You'll need to re-add your sources.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Is the `again` part of the command?

Comment: can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`?

Comment: No. I put the character in the wrong place.

Comment: Zacharee1 i got lots of  error through your code. tellme how can i correct them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are no `utilities-1.4` package in MySQL repo. There is only `utilities-1.5`.

I can only assume that you might be having `utilities-1.4`in your `mysql.list`. The [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192180/debian-problems-updating-mysql-5-6) is to reconfigure mysql by:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config
```

Select 'Utilities'-> OK -> mysql-utilities-1.5 -> OK -> Apply

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: @Ankit_Chaudhary If you find the post useful you can accept this as the answer to your question ;)